# Why does strcat to getenv() changes subsequent getenv() calls?

Tags: c++, c, getenv

I use `getenv()` in my c code.

Here is the code I use

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
    char *path=getenv("USERPROFILE");
    strcat(path,"\\bullshit");
    char *newpath=getenv("USERPROFILE");
    printf("%s",newpath);
}
```

The result of the print statement is

```
C:\Users\username\bullshit
```

Why does the `getenv()` call to environment variable change due to `strcat`?

NOTE: I am using minw-gcc compiler 32-bit on windows 8.1 system

Comment: Yeah i got it.Thanks.

Comment: According to the C standard, modifying a string returned by `getenv()` - for example, by appending something to it using `strcat()` - gives undefined behaviour.    Practically, if `getenv()` uses a `static` pointer internally, the effect of `strcat()` may be to modify the string seen by other calls of `getenv()` - since they may all return the same pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't own the string returned by `getenv`, you can't modify it (like for example appending something to it).

If you need to modify it, then copy it to memory you own and can modify, like an array:

```
char path[PATH_MAX];
strcpy(path, getenv(...));
strcat(path, ...);
```

---

As noted this can lead to buffer-overflows, so a safer method could be to use `strncpy`. But then remember there's a case where it won't add the string null-terminator so it needs to be added explicitly.

Comment: Note: someone can crash this code by setting USERPROFILE to something longer than PATH_MAX (it doesn't need to be a valid path)

Comment: @Hasturkun Except that it only allocates enough memory for the string itself, so it can't be appended to.

Comment: Systems like Linux also support longer paths so using strlen to allocate a long enough buffer dynamically would be better.